# Is it okay to show the loads of data on modal or on the new web page?

Tags: gui-design, modal-windows, wireframe, modal, modal-view

I am working on an application which has some data in tabular format. There is a view button for each row.

So my question is:

After clicking on that button, should I show the data on the new web page or should I just show it in the same page but in a modal dialog?

The data I am going to show after clicking on the view button will have around 7-8 labels with their respective values and also at the bottom there will be table with 3 columns with pagination.

In my opinion new page will be good option for the UX but if I use a modal there will be no back button click; also there won't be any delay. So I'm kind of confused with this. Which one should I prefer?

- Modal
- New page

Comment: What are the users trying to do? Do you anticipate them drilling in, looking at the content, then coming back to the list frequently? Are there CRUD actions on the drilldown content?

Comment: Yeah there might be chance that users will be coming back to the listing page frequently and yes there are CRUD operations

Comment: see my answer below. With a side sheet (sliding panel), there's opportunity to see substantial amounts of data, and perform CRUD w/o 'leaving' the primary view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There's another option to consider: a **[side sheet](https://material.io/components/sheets-side#anatomy)**.

From Material Design:

> Side sheets can display a wide variety of content and layouts, ranging from a list of actions to supplemental content in a tabular layout.
>
> **Standard side sheets** display content that complements the screen’s primary content. They remain visible while users interact with primary content.
>
> **Modal side sheets** are used on mobile instead of standard side sheets, due to limited screen size. They can display the same types of content as standard side sheets, but must be dismissed in order to interact with the underlying content.

[image]

Side sheets (also called sliding panels) allow a user to feel like they haven't 'left' the page, since the content underneath peeks out. This pattern is often used when you want to keep people feeling connected to the main view, especially if they wish to:

- examine supplemental values
- quickly modify a property

You can vary the width of a side sheet, depending on the amount of content you need to display (like a table).

Comment: Thanks this will work I guess